# Listar en Tabla java

Tags: java, java-swing

Buen dia, 
el problema es el siguiente, tengo un ArrayList de Empleados y eso lo necesito mostrar en un JTable el problema es que se debe buscar por un id, al momento de buscarlo solo me debe listar los datos de esa persona, resulta que cuando yo busco en el ArrayList me muestra todos los elementos del ArrayList

codigo para mostrar en el jtable

```
public void mostrarEmpleado() {

        String matriz[][] = new String[empleado.size()][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < empleado.size(); i++) {
            matriz[i][0] = empleado.get(i).getId();
            matriz[i][1] = empleadon.get(i).getNombre() + " " + empleado.get(i).getApellido();
            matriz[i][2] = (formatoFecha.format(empleado.get(i).getAnioNac())).toString();
            matriz[i][3] = (formato.format(empleado.get(i).calcular())).toString();

        }
        tablaMostrar.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                matriz,
                new String[]{
                    "Id", "Nombre y apellido", "Fecha de nac", "Salario"
                }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tablaMostrar);
    }
```

codigo para buscar en el ArrayList

```
public boolean buscar() {
        boolean encontrado = false;
        int i = 0;

        while (encontrado == false && i < empleado.size()) {

            if (empleado.get(i).getId().equals(txtBuscarEmp.getText())) {
                encontrado = true;

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Lo encontro");
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        if (encontrado) {
             mostrarEmpleado();

            }
            return false;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existe, intenta nuevamente, ..");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿El problema cuál es? ¿Te sale el mensaje de "Lo encontro" o no? En todo caso, en "mostrarEmpleado" no filtras, así que te mostrará todos los datos; el JTable no va a relacionar los datos con la búsqueda que hagas antes "mágicamente", eres tú quien debe filtrar los datos de una forma u otra.

Comment: o sea corrigo esa parte, yo coloco un mensaje que diga que encontro para guiarme que si entro porque de otra manera si lo que se busca no existe en el ArrayList el manda un mensaje que no existe, lo que deseo es que la tabla solo me muestre un elemento y ese sea el que busque, porque yo busco, encuentro, pero muestra todos los elementos del ArrayList, necesito filtrar eso

Comment: En la tabla le pasas una matriz que tiene todos los elementos del `ArrayList`. Pásale solo los que quieras mostrar.

Comment: Como? Ilustrame